# Enumerate the basic data types in C so that the sizes can be easily accessed

Tags: c, arrays, types, sizeof

Is it possible to get sizes of all basic datatypes in C using a for loop? For example, can we do something like this?

```
#include <datatypes.h> /* or something else which defines get_data_types() */
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int x = 0; x < len(get_data_types()); x++) {
        printf("Size of %s is %d", get_data_types()[x], sizeof(get_data_types()[x]));
    }
 }
```

I could enumerate all the datatypes by replacing the for loop and writing individual statements for `int`, `long`, etc. However, I am wondering if it is possible to have a for loop to do the same?

Essentially, I am trying to avoid the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Size of int is %d", sizeof(int);
    printf("Size of unsigned int is %d", sizeof(unsigned int);
    printf("Size of long is %d", sizeof(long);
    /* etc. */
    return 0;
}
```

**Data types of interest** - `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char`, `int`, `unsigned int`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `float`, `double`, `long double`

**Clarification**: I don't necessarily want an array of mixed types, but to be able to enumerate the types so that the sizes can be easily accessed.

Comment: You cannot mix datatypes in an array in C. Well, you can achieve something similar by trickery, but you cannot get the type of a particular place in memory.

Comment: C has an infinite number of data types: `int`, `int*`, `int**`, `int***`, ..., `int[1]`, `int[2]`, ..., `enum A`, `enum B`, `struct A`, `struct B`, .... Do you mean basic/arithmetic types?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I meant that. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @klutt I get it. What's the easiest workaround?

Comment: The work around is to list the types you want sizes of and compute their sizes.   The number of "basic" types  (in the sense of not defined in terms of one or more another types) is pretty small. The number of derived types (defined in terms of one or more other types) approaches infinity (e.g. struct and enumerated types, pointers, arrays (of different sizes - each size has a different type) of all basic and derived types, etc).In practice, you will only need sizes of basic types (like `int`, `float`, etc) and a few derived types (structs, pointers, arrays, etc).

Comment: For any signed integer type, it's corresponding unsigned type has the same size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible. There's no way to automatically list all types in C. You have to do this manually for each type.

However, if you are using the information a lot, you can always prepare a list in advance. There are some ways to do it. This is one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int size;
} type;

int main()
{
    type types[3] = { {"int", sizeof (int) },
                      {"char", sizeof (char) },
                      {"double", sizeof (double) } };

    for (int x = 0; x<sizeof(types)/sizeof(types[0]); x++)
        printf("Size of %s is %d\n", types[x].name, types[x].size);
}
```

(Code simplified with inspiration of Paul Ogilvie's answer below.)

In a comment to this answer you asked: *Can we just create an array like the following : types_array = {"int", "char", "double", "long"} and while iterating over this get the corresponding sizes? I mean to say using some function f, can we assign types[j].size to sizeof(f(types_array[j]))*

In short, no. This is because C is a strongly typed compiled language. In languages like Python and PHP you can do all sorts of fancy stuff like that, but in C no. Not without trickery. The function `f` in your example must have a specified return type, and this is the type `sizeof` will get as argument.

One way to get around it is to write a custom sizeof:

```
int mysizeof(char * s) {
    if(strcmp(s, "char") == 0)
        return sizeof(char);
    if(strcmp(s, "int") == 0)
        return sizeof(int);
}
```

If this list is long, you could use a macro:

```
#define MYSIZEOF(x) if(strcmp(s, #x) == 0) return sizeof(x)

int mysizeof(char * s) {
    MYSIZEOF(int);
    MYSIZEOF(char);
    MYSIZEOF(double);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @klutt. This looks reasonable. Can we just create an array like the following : types_array = {"int", "char", "double", "long"} and while iterating over this get the corresponding sizes? I mean to say using some function `f`, can we assign types[j].size to sizeof(f(types_array[j]))

Comment: @NipunBatra No, you cannot.  Such things cannot be done in a strongly typed compiled language.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is not possible, the various types must be enumerated explicitly, one way or another, but you can make an array of structures, use a convenience macro to intialize it simply and write a loop to output all standard type sizes.

Note that you forgot a few useful standard types:

- more integral types: `long long`, `unsigned long long`, `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `intmax_t`, `uintmax_t`, `wchar_t`...
- pointer types: `void *`, `char *`, `int *`...
- function pointer types: `void(*)(void)`

Here is an implementation:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TYPEDESC(t)  { #t, sizeof(t) }

static struct type_desc {
    const char *name;
    int size;
} const types[] = {
    TYPEDESC(char), TYPEDESC(unsigned char), TYPEDESC(signed char),
    TYPEDESC(wchar_t),
    TYPEDESC(short), TYPEDESC(unsigned short),
    TYPEDESC(int), TYPEDESC(unsigned int),
    TYPEDESC(long), TYPEDESC(unsigned long),
    TYPEDESC(long long), TYPEDESC(unsigned long long),
    TYPEDESC(float), TYPEDESC(double), TYPEDESC(long double),
    TYPEDESC(size_t), TYPEDESC(ptrdiff_t),
    TYPEDESC(intmax_t), TYPEDESC(uintmax_t),
    TYPEDESC(void *), TYPEDESC(char *), TYPEDESC(int *),
    TYPEDESC(void (*)(void)),
};

int main() {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(types) / sizeof(types[0]); i++)
        printf("sizeof( %s ) = %d\n", types[i].name, types[i].size);
    return 0;
}
```

The output on my 64-bit OS/X system is this:

```
sizeof( char ) = 1
sizeof( unsigned char ) = 1
sizeof( signed char ) = 1
sizeof( wchar_t ) = 4
sizeof( short ) = 2
sizeof( unsigned short ) = 2
sizeof( int ) = 4
sizeof( unsigned int ) = 4
sizeof( long ) = 8
sizeof( unsigned long ) = 8
sizeof( long long ) = 8
sizeof( unsigned long long ) = 8
sizeof( float ) = 4
sizeof( double ) = 8
sizeof( long double ) = 16
sizeof( size_t ) = 8
sizeof( ptrdiff_t ) = 8
sizeof( intmax_t ) = 8
sizeof( uintmax_t ) = 8
sizeof( void * ) = 8
sizeof( char * ) = 8
sizeof( int * ) = 8
sizeof( void (*)(void) ) = 8
```

It may come as a surprise that `wchar_t` is 32-bits and `long double` 16 byte long. This does not mean that `long double` values use all 128 bits for the floating point representation. The output will be very different on a Windows system.

Comment: However, for instance `sizeof (char*) == sizeof(int(*)(double, long))` will always evaluate to true.

Comment: @klutt: I don't think so: function pointers may be smaller than generic pointers on some architectures. It used to be the case on x86 segmented architectures in Medium mode, small code+large data. Is there something in the C Standard that supports your statement?

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Interesting. I did suspect that the C standard for obvious reasons did not dictate that all pointers should have the same size, but I thought that in practice that were the case.

Comment: @klutt: the C Standard does not mandate that pointers to different types have the same size. Pointers to `char` may for example be larger than pointers to `int`, as was the case on older Cray computers. In practice, for user code, it is almost always the case, and it is mandatory on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 2):

Klutt's answer can be a bit simplified to:

```
struct {
    char *name;
    int size;
} types[] = {
    {"int", sizeof(int)},
    {"char", sizeof(char)},
    {"long", sizeof(long)}
    //.. etcetera
};

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<sizeof(types)/sizeof(types[0]); i++)
        printf("sizeof %s = %d\n",types[i].name, types[i].size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I referenced this answer, because I did not want to steal it.

Comment: @Klutt, yea, it is all static/compile time. Should make it to `const char *name` as the literal will be read-only.